# Error when plotting titanic data '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

Tags: python

Trying to plot the following:

```
bins = [50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, np.inf]
labels = ['£50', '£100', '£150', '£200', '£250', '£300']
df_train['Fare'] = pd.cut(df_train['Fare'], bins, labels=labels)
sns.barplot(x="Fare", y="Survived", data=df_train)
plt.show()
```

And got error:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'.

[image]

Any suggestion how to fix it?

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: Please put tracebacks and error messages as text into your quesiton. Not as an image. What does your dataframe look like and what are the dtypes of the columns?

Comment: Just to add that if I restart kernel, plotting works but if I amend anything in the code without restart of kernel from the beginning error appears again

Comment: I have the feeling that `bins` and `labels` should have the same type